# Filter tcp packet payload length in tcpdump

Tags: tcpdump, tshark

The `greater` filter filters packets by their total length. Is it possible to filter by the payload's length? I know this is possible as a display filter, but I was wondering if it's possible to do this in a capture filter.

Comment: Ethernet payload? IP packet payload? UDP payload? TCP payload?

Comment: Sorry for not specifying, this was tcp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method to do this is *almost* given as an example in [`tcpdump`](https://manpages.debian.org/tcpdump/tcpdump.8#EXAMPLES)'s manual, for the IPv4 case:

> To print all IPv4 HTTP packets to and from port 80, i.e. print only packets that contain data, not, for example, SYN and FIN packets and ACK-only packets. (IPv6 is left as an exercise for the reader.)
>
> ```
> tcpdump 'tcp port 80 and (((ip[2:2] - ((ip[0]&0xf)<<2)) - ((tcp[12]&0xf0)>>2)) != 0)'
> ```

The *tcpdump*'s expression is compiled into [BPF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_Packet_Filter) [bytecode](https://blog.cloudflare.com/bpf-the-forgotten-bytecode/) (try adding the option `-d` to `tcpdump` to see how it looks like), that can dereference pointers and do some arithmetic and bitwise operations on them.

The `tcp` match and the `tcp[]` dereference above don't allow to simply filter for TCP payload size. So the next filter substracts to the total [IPv4 packet length](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4#Total_Length) the (variable) [IP header length](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4#IHL) to get the remaining [TCP segment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#TCP_segment_structure) length, then substract from the result the [TCP segment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#TCP_segment_structure) data offset (thus removing the TCP segment header + options length). If the value remaining is non-zero, that means there is data in the payload.

So for example to match any IPv4 packet with a TCP data payload between 4 and 6 bytes on the *eth0* interface, this would be:

```
tcpdump -n -s0 -p -i eth0 'ip and tcp and (((ip[2:2] - ((ip[0]&0xf)<<2)) - ((tcp[12]&0xf0)>>2)) >= 4) and (((ip[2:2] - ((ip[0]&0xf)<<2)) - ((tcp[12]&0xf0)>>2)) <= 6)'
```

Don't worry the compiled bytecode (again, that can be displayed by adding the `-d` option) is optimized and the result takes (here, Linux, tcpdump 4.9.3 and libpcap 1.8.3) only one more line of bytecode to add the second comparison despite the repetition.

Comment: I understand BPF can't do loops, so IPv6 is more complex, with its variable number of extension headers. I'll do like in the manual, leave as an exercise the IPv6 case. Maybe doing a kind of loop unrolling with the case of 0,1,2,...,10 additional headers before the upper tcp layer could be imagined, or maybe there's a completely different and easier method available.